# Constructed stylesheet override :host css in ionic framework

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, angular14, ionic6

I want to override the inset css in host styling in ionic style but it's not overriding, please look at the following code.

```
existing code is 

:host {
    inset: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    }
required code

 :host {
    inset: unset;
    position: relative;
    }
```

FYI - I am using angular14 and ionic6
[please check attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbBmA.png)

Answer (score -1):

This may be a trivial thing to say, but styles are reproduced from the top in them and therefore if you have a style below that contradicts the one above it, the one below will work. Or you can rigidly set the style example - .class {style: code!important; }

Comment: I have already tried it but its not working :host {
    inset: unset !important;
    position: relative !important;
    }